# Pass a JavaScript function with PHP after AJAX call is done

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, function

What I'm doing is checking a users status in the database.

The PHP page echo's the status back to the ajax call and depending on the status a function is being executed.

This works well. I know I could use json, but for now this is fine.
What I'd like is not to echo the users status, but to echo the function that should be executed and execute it after ajax is done.

My jQuery/ajax code:

```
function checkstatus() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./query/checkstatus.php",
    data: {}
    }).done(function(result) {
      if (result == "nieuw") {
        loadHomeNieuw();
      };
      if (result == "actief") {
        loadHome();
      };
    });
}
```

What I'd like but is not working.
jQuery/ajax code:

```
function checkstatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./query/checkstatus.php",
        data: {}
    }).done(function(result) {
    });
}
```

PHP code (not working):

```
if ($status == "nieuw") {
    echo "loadHomeNieuw();";
}

if ($status == "actief") {
    echo "loadHome();";
}
```

Is this even possible? The reason why I'm asking, is that I feel it's safer. It might be possible to hack the status as a user...so he can change it and  the wrong function is being called. If I do this on the server side, it's way safer.

Or are there better options?

Comment: It's not way safer, it's exactly the same. Getting the response from the ajax call on the client side is trivial.

Comment: why you echo `"loadHomeNieuw();"` just call it like `if(){ loadHomeNieuw() }`

Comment: If it isn't safer...then forget my question. But it feels safer...

And the reason I don't do it like that, is because my php page and javascript are on 2 different pages. So that won't work right?

Comment: It's not safer in any way. Sending the function name as a string to the client is just as easy for someone to figure out, if not easier, than just calling the function directly. Tools like Fiddler lets you see the response and the function name will be clear as day.

Comment: Ok, so what do you suggest? getScript seems safe? the eval() and window() method seem to do the same thing as I'm doing now, but just in a different way...

Answer (score 0):

You can call eval

```
function checkstatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./query/checkstatus.php",
        data: {}
    }).done(function(result) {
        eval(result);
    });
}
```

but some people say that's evil so you can just return a name and execute a function that have that name:

```
function checkstatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./query/checkstatus.php",
        data: {}
    }).done(function(result) {
        window[result]();
    });
}
```

and in php just echo name

```
if ($status == "nieuw") {
    echo "loadHomeNieuw";
} else if ($status == "actief") {
    echo "loadHome";
}
```

Comment: Ah, both options work. With the 1st one I have to echo loadHome(); and with the 2nd option I only have to echo loadHome.
But is any of these options better/safer than what I'm doing now? Or can you return a different name (and then call another function) for both?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called GetScript: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

this wil execute the returned code.
the code :

```
$.getScript("./query/checkstatus.php");
```

Comment: Ok, so now I have 3 options :D Nice, but which one is the best one? getScript, eval or window? And why? I can image getScript is the safest one...?

Comment: Its is made for this purpose at least.